# where can i get jmagick.jar and jmagik.dll for 64 bit windows os download

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

I have `Windows 64 bit version` and I have installed Java jdk. I followed these steps.

1. I installed **ImageMagick-6.8.7-10-Q16-x64-dll.exe**
2. Downloaded **jmagick-win-6.3.9-Q16.zip** and extracted to get `jmagick.jar` & `jmagick.dll`
3. Copied `jmagick.jar` & `jmagick.dll` to **java_home\jre\jdk\jre\lib\ext folder**
4. Copied `jmagick.dll` into **C:\windows\system32 folder**

but i getting following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load MagickLoader (class not found)
at magick.Magick.<clinit>(Magick.java:25)
at com.java.servlets.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:47)
at com.java.servlets.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```